# Code keeps returning "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I keep running into `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` errors, but I can't see where I'm missing/have an extra `;` or `)` character. It gives me a line in the code (see below), but it *appears* to be a valid token placement.

JSLint gives me some clarification: `Expected ')' to match '(' from line 2 and instead saw ';'.`

Below is the JavaScript code I'm writing (inner sections removed for brevity):

```
'use strict';
(function() {
    AppCtrl = function($scope) {
      //JSON data
    };
    window.AppCtrl = AppCtrl;
  }; //Error shows up on this line
  // Declare app level module which depends on views and components
  angular.module('careApp', [
    //Dependencies
  ])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    //if given invalid partial, go back to appLaunch.html
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/appLaunch'
    });
  }])
  .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', window.AppCtrl]);

  var patientID = ''; $scope.idStore = function() {
    //stuff
  }
  $scope.patientTime = function() {
    //more stuff

  }
})();
```

Comment: Yeah, that line shouldn't be there.

Comment: Why? It contains the `AppCtrl` function, right? Removing that line wouldn't do any good.

Comment: `};` is ending your function: so its basically `(function(){};` which is invalid syntax because you cannot have multiple statements inside `()`. You already closed off `AppCtrl` above the `window.AppCtrl =` line

Comment: The indentation in the line above that is not right, that's what's confusing you.

Comment: I've correct the indentation in your code. Now you should be able to see that you have an extra closing brace after `window.AppCtrl = AppCtrl`. You've already closed off the `AppCtrl` function and now you're trying to close something else.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up. Removing that line results in `AppCtrl is not defined`, however. Is there something else I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: @Thassa You never declared `AppCtrl`. Put a `var` in front of `AppCtrl`. (`var AppCtrl = ...`)

Comment: @MikeC that results in a `$scope is not defined` error, even with correct declarations.

Comment: @Thassa That didn't cause `$scope` to be undefined. You're, again, using a variable when it doesn't exist. `$scope.patientTime = ...` and everything else using `$scope` here should be inside of the `AppCtrl` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105947/discussion-between-thassa-and-mike-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @MikeC for his help in solving the problem. While the indentation was a critical part of the issue, it didn't solve the underlying problem: **how the variable AppCtrl was defined.**

To solve it, let's look at the various ways we *could* define AppCtrl:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {...}])

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {...})

var MyCtrl = function ($scope) {...})
```

We are currently using the third definition, which isn't working in our favor now. The first definition appears to be closer to what we want. With that in mind...

```
'use strict';

  // Declare app level module which depends on views and components
  angular.module('careApp', [
     //Dependencies
  ])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      //if given invalid partial, go back to appLaunch.html
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/appLaunch'});
  }])
  .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.list = [
               //JSON data
            ];
            var patientID = '';
            $scope.idStore = function() {
             //Stuff
            }
            $scope.patientTime = function(){
              //More stuff
            }
  }]);
```

...Here's the correct configuration.

Note that we removed the `(function() {` block up at the very top of the JS file, as well as the appropriate closing elements at the very bottom. We also moved the `$scope.list` and other `$scope` functions into the `.controller` portion of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Brackets are wrong, see picture. I had some time off.

[image]